# How do I add an animated video as a splash screen in Unity3D android game?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I'm using Unity3D for my android game. I want to add a video as an animated splash screen. I've tried different methods to do so. My code in C# looks like this:

```
public class Splash : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        StartCoroutine ("PlayMovie");
    }
    public IEnumerator PlayMovie ()
    {
        Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie ("splash.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Hidden, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
        Application.LoadLevel ("home");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use it like this

```
public bool started = false;

void Update ()
{
    if (started == false) {
        started = true;
        StartCoroutine (playMovie ());
    }
}

public IEnumerator PlayMovie ()
{      
   yield Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie ("splash.mp4", 
   Color.black,FullScreenMovieControlMode.Hidden, 
   FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit);

   Application.LoadLevel ("home");
}
```

you should also check for the documentation

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html